# Please check this wordpress script which queries all posts with the same tag

Tags: php, wordpress

please check this wordpress script for me, it is not working. I want to get the first tag of the post and query all other posts who have the same tag. TY!

```
<? // Start related posts by tag 
$posttags = get_the_tags();
$count=0;
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $count++;
    if (1 == $count) {
      $tag = $tag->slug . ' ';
    }
  }
}

query_posts('tag='.$tag.'&posts_per_page=-1');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

<? endwhile; 
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the rest of the logic of your code but one problem is the fact that you are using the same `$tag` variable to loop through the `$posttags` as well as store your first tag value. Instead of doing something so complex, why not just use the first value in your `$posttags` array.

Something like this -

```
<? // Start related posts by tag 
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    query_posts('tag='.$posttags[0].'&posts_per_page=-1');
    //rest of your code here
```